# How to add string to string with strpor in conditions?

Tags: php

I want to if both conditions is true, add both word to `$b`. I don’t want to use `if(strpos($a, ‘lo’) && strpos($a, ‘he’))` condition.

My code:

```
$a = ‘hello’;
$b = ‘’;

if (strpos($a, ‘lo’) { $b .= ‘lo’; }
else if (strpos($a, ‘he’) { $b .= ‘he’; }

echo $b;
```

Comment: Yeh thats alot of code.... we are not going to write you your code

Comment: Sorry, I’m edited, I wrote this question from my mobile, and stackoverflow didn’t show my code between the php tags.

Comment: your code is missing a `)` at the end of both `if` and `else if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
$a = "hello";
$b = "";

if (strpos($a, "he") !== false) {
    $b .= 'he';
    if (strpos($a, "lo") !== false) { 
        $b .= 'lo';
    }
}

echo $b;
```